# Using Drush on shared hosting without `curl` and `wget`

Tags: 7, drush, ssh

I have a Drupal 7 site installed on shared hosting.

And installed Drush:8.1.17 with composer and cgr all is working well except `drush up` because hosting provider does not support `curl` or `wget` on shared accounts.

When I ask them they said that there is no plans for giving permissions on shared account users to `curl` or `wget` when I run:

```
$ drush up  
$ wget nor curl executable found.

$ curl
-jailshell: /usr/bin/curl: Permission denied
```

Is there another way of using `drush up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is not supported. You'll have to update locally and then push to your provider.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Until this case I made exactly that to every site I am maintaining but for that I  try to shortcut the process and shoot myself in the foot :).